# Trying to eliminate emailing page 2 on fastreports

Tags: fastreport

Good day

I have a template setup on fastreports, and what I am trying to do is that when the template is printed, it should print page 1 and page 2 but when it is emailed, it should only email page 1

my coding is as follow:

```
procedure Page2OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
 if (<Document_Information."Method">) = 'Emailed' then
  Page2.Visible := false
  else
  Page2.Visible := true;       
end;
```

But when emailing the template, it still emails page 2, any advise?

Comment: That is definitely not C++. Pascal maybe?

Comment: I have no idea what this is, but it sure is not c++. Try to find better tags for you question and you might reach more people familiar with your problem.